# Error while loading items to sharepoint from CSV file

Tags: csv, datetime, field

I am using a small script based on C# that load items automatically from CSV file to a sharepoint list. However, I get an error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime at a specific item

I found out that the issue is caused by this value "Hello again - September 19, 2014"

If I replace the comma manually by another character manually, it works fine.

The column where that field is supposed to be sent has single text type.

How do I get around this issue?

Comment: Does the format always has '-' dashes? If yes, you can split the data into 2 by dashes and get the last index.

Comment: no it doesn't always come with dashes.

Comment: @Jim87, could you post the script?